# Why can't load more data for ListView

Tags: flutter, dart

For example i just want to fetch only 5 data in list and scroll down for load more data but it doesn't work it appear to fetch all data and load the same data when scroll down... Is it the way i limit for fetch data is no right because it fetch all data not parse the data for only 5.... Can somebody help me fix this

postData.dart

```
class PostData extends StatefulWidget {
  const PostData({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _PostDataState createState() => _PostDataState();
}

class _PostDataState extends State<PostData> {
List getData = List();
  ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    fetchFive();

    _scrollController.addListener(() {
      if (_scrollController.position.pixels ==
          _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent) {
        fetchFive();
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _scrollController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Load Page"),
          toolbarHeight: 65,
          backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent[700],
        ),
        body: ListView.builder(
            controller: _scrollController,
            itemCount: getData.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Card(
                child: GestureDetector(
                  child: ListTile(
                      title: Text(getData[index]['no_siri'].toString()),
                      subtitle: Text(getData[index]['lokasi'].toString())),
                ),
              );
            }));
  }

  fetch() async {
    final response =
        await http.get('https://my-json-server.typicode.com/typicode/demo/posts');

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      setState(() {
        final data = json.decode(response.body);
        for (var i in data) {
          getData.add(i);
        }
      });
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load data');
    }
  }

  fetchFive() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      fetch();
    }
  }
```

getData.dart
model json

```
class Users {
  final int no;
  final String nosiri;
  final String lokasi;
  final String status;
  final String pemilik;
  final String barcode;
  final String thumbnailurl;

  Users(
      {this.no,
      this.nosiri,
      this.lokasi,
      this.status,
      this.pemilik,
      this.barcode,
      this.thumbnailurl});

  factory Users.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Users(
      no: json['no'],
      nosiri: json['no_siri'],
      lokasi: json['lokasi'],
      status: json['status'],
      pemilik: json['pemilik'],
      barcode: json['barcodedata'],
      thumbnailurl: json['thumbnailurl'],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hakim! You have to implement `Pagination` on your `REST API` and then you would be able to just call:

```
final response =
    await http.get('https://my-json-server.typicode.com/typicode/demo/posts?page=XXX&pageSize=5');
```

Where `XXX` is your currently requested page number.

Comment: it still same. it fetch all data and when i scroll down it duplicate the data  it doesn't seperate the data. So what's the problem is?

Comment: Do you have `pagination` implemented on the server-side? If you don't have the arguments after `?` are ignored. You should **NOT** do this on the client side.

Comment: I can't quite understand is it you mean in my json data is include for pagination?